# Installing Kibana 4.2

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am trying to install Kibana 4.2 with Elasticsearch 2.0. I'm getting this error message:

[image]

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more. Is ES up and running? What process are you following to install Kibana? Does your Kibana config correctly point to your running ES cluster? The more you tell the bigger the chances of getting answers ;-)

Comment: Try with another browser, I got the same error in Chrome, but it worked on Vivaldi and Firefox. This is a browser support issue.

Comment: Thanks, it was the version of chrome. After update chrome It works great